# Tabbar in phonegap android

Tags: android, tabs, cordova, back

I'm trying to add native **tab** to my phonegap application on Android. I have a way of doing it where each tab has it's own Activity and use loadUrl to load **Phonegap** in the view but it raises the following problem:

If I go back to a tab, the last instance state has been saved, so if i
clicked on a link from the tab, clicking back on the tab doesn't load
**back the main page**.

Comment: I keep meaning to look into this. I would love a plugin much like the NativeControls plugin for iOS that would do a native Android tab bar.

Comment: in my app i want the tabbar at top of the device ,pls help me .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use jquery-mobile to generate your tabs
like the following [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/VywZa/)